# How to convert *ldap.Entry to Array object

Tags: go, active-directory, ldap

I have the following code that does a basic query:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "gopkg.in/ldap.v3"
  "log"
)

func main(){
  //First off, we connect to the LDAP server
  ldapURL := "ldaps://test.io:636"
  l, err := ldap.DialURL(ldapURL)
  if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer l.Close()

  //Now we bind to it with credentials.
  err = l.Bind("CN=ad_binder,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io", "Password")
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }

  //After we've binded, we now query the LDAP server.
  baseDN := "dc=test,dc=io"
  filter := "(objectclass=*)"

  // Creates search request for LDAP server.
  searchReq := ldap.NewSearchRequest(baseDN, ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, 0, 0, 0, false, filter, []string{}, []ldap.Control{})

  // Gets the results of the search request.
  result, err := l.Search(searchReq)
  if err != nil {
          //return fmt.Errorf("failed to query LDAP: %w", err)
  }

  //Prints all the attributes per entry in the search result.
  for _, entry := range result.Entries {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", entry)
    //entry.Print()
    fmt.Println()
  }
}
```

With this code, I'm able to tell that the type that "entry" is is *ldap.Entry.

However, I would like to translate these to array objects to add to one array for comparison later. Essentially, creating an array of all the LDAP entries in the query result.

Some of the attributes are in base 64 as well, so that does need to be accounted for, since they do not print out properly right now with entry.Print().

For instance, I have objectsid, dnsrecord, and ipsecdata that are all base 64. Then I would do

EDIT (11/18/2020):

```
//If the current LDAP attribute is in base 64, make sure it's encoded to base 64 when adding to the array.
if(entry[i] == "objectguid"){
  new_array[] = base64_encode(entry[i])
  } elseif(entry[i] == "dnsrecord"){
    new_array[] = base64_encode(entry[i])
  } elseif(entry[i] == "ipsecdata"){
    new_array[] = base64_encode(entry[i])
  }
//Now for any attributes that aren't in base 64 originally, just add to the array as normal.
else{
new_array[] = entry[i]
}
```

Currently, if I query the LDAP server right now, here's an entry I receive from go:

```
DN: CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=test,DC=io
objectClass: [top group]
cn: [Remote Desktop Users]
uSNCreated: [3571]
objectGUID: [??8:@?$??)B?]
objectSid: [ +]
uSNChanged: [8916]
```

The objectGUID and objectSid should have the following values when encoded properly:

```
            [objectguid] => 6wiJ9Tg6f0CqJIDbKUKrEA==
            [objectsid] => AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAKwIAAA==
```

So the end result in my array should have the following:

```
DN: CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=test,DC=io
objectClass: [top group]
cn: [Remote Desktop Users]
uSNCreated: [3571]
objectguid : 6wiJ9Tg6f0CqJIDbKUKrEA==
objectsid : AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAKwIAAA==
uSNChanged: [8916]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the entries may have attributes with multiple values, you may want to try with the available api which method call will attend your needs. in the worst case scenario you will have an inner loop.

if I understood correctly you want to identify base64 values and decide to encode or decode them. thanks to encoding/base64 package we can check this easily.

```
var ans []string
for _, entry := range result.Entries {
    v := entry.GetAttributeValue("objectguid")
    if !isBase64(v) {
        ans = append(ans, base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(v)))
        continue
    }

    ans = append(ans, v)
}

func isBase64(s string) bool {
    _, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(strings.TrimSpace(s))
    return err == nil
}
```

you could also iterate over the attributes to identify them by their name

```
for _, entry := range result.Entries {
    for _, attr := range entry.Attributes {
        switch attr.Name {
            case "objectguid":
                s, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(attr.Values[0]) // make sure to iterate the values properly
                fmt.Println(string(s))
            case "dnsrecord":
                fmt.Println("dsn record")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. For example, I have 16 attributes in one single LDAP entry. 3 of those attributes are in base64 in the LDAP server, so I need to encode them back to base64 when adding to the array. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: @tobeydw all good. I think the answer still gives enough infos to achieve that, is there anything which is not there ?